# /dev/md1 full, 486M /486M, hard drives are 3TB, can't install new packages

Tags: storage

As the question says, this is happening.

```
udev            7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.6G  196M  1.4G  13% /run
/dev/md2       1007G   24G  932G   3% /
tmpfs           7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/md1        488M  486M     0 100% /boot
/dev/md3        1.7T   77M  1.7T   1% /home
tmpfs           1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /run/user/0
```

I really could use some help, as i'm currently trying to install Jansi, but I cannot install any more of the required packages.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/171209/my-boot-partition-hit-100-and-now-i-cant-upgrade-cant-remove-old-kernels-to

Comment: Have already tried that, none of it worked.

Comment: What were the exact steps you tried, and what output did you get?

Comment: When kernels were being deleted, it decided to delete the newer versions of it too, and I got spooked and cancelled the operation. Not only did it take 4.0.4-145, it took the rest of it with it.

Comment: "_can't install new packages_" please [edit] your question to explain what you're trying, and what happens when you do try. Remember to include any messages that are output. (Is it possible that you've a kernel upgrade scheduled? That would fail without space on `/boot`.)

Comment: It's no fun to grow the size of the boot volume of a running system. And there should be no reason for a boot volume to reach half a GByte, so please show the `du -sm /boot/*`

Answer (score -1):

Why is your /boot/ this size?

I would suggest booting with a live gparted media and adjust your partitions sizes from there.

And by the way, backup your stuffs before in case of